# Error al clonar proyecto flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo un problema, tengo un proyecto en mi pc y lo tengo en github private, al tiempo de clonarlo en otra pc o en mi misma pc en otra carpeta me da un error al querer correrlo en algun android

Este es el error que me da:

```
    Output:  C:\Users\pptav\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\cb57fa545ea217ee323f0982a2c37654\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\pptav\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\cb57fa545ea217ee323f0982a2c37654\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\pptav\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\18687a6f2e2f9847b7546090ab2a5ee0\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          E:\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          Z:\FlutterProjects\BarajaLoteriaFlutter2\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          Z:\FlutterProjects\BarajaLoteriaFlutter2\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @Z:\FlutterProjects\BarajaLoteriaFlutter2\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          Z:\FlutterProjects\BarajaLoteriaFlutter2\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.zimbronapps.loteria\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          Z:\FlutterProjects\BarajaLoteriaFlutter2\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Ejecuta `flutter doctor -v` y adjunta la salida (lo que te imprime)

Comment: Al final, no supe que error tenia pero quité el package de permission_handler y me solucionó